# Morphism can be pulled through braid crossings

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, braidings

I stumbled upon this statement in the context of monoidal braided categories. How do I see, as pointed out in the text, that this follows from functoriality? Here is the [source](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Braided_category)

[image]

Comment: that diagram is a direct translation of the definition of functoriality given in the third displayed equation in the article (which you should link!)

Comment: Sorry I added the link. I see, but it seems to me in some definitions this is avoided or concluded? For example here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/braided+monoidal+category. Or does functorial also mean natural?

Comment: in the nlab link, the naturality of the braiding at a morphism $W \to Z$ is where that diagram would come from